# Invoking methods on ActiveX interface without a Wrapper class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, com, activex

I am using a 3d party ActiveX component for which there is no source code. I can add the component to my MFC dialog . When I do that, a wrapper class gets created with lots of functions which look like this:

```
void SetNextMovePCI2FastLink(short nNodeNumber, short nCardNumber)
    {
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I2 VTS_I2 ;
        InvokeHelper(0x109, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, nNodeNumber, nCardNumber);
    }
```

Using these wrapper functions I can have normal operation. However, due to accessing the COM object from different threads, I need to marshal the COM Interface for this object. How do I invoke methods on the COM Interface directly without the wrapper? Is there a simple way to apply the wrapper to the raw COM interface, so wrapper could be back in use? Or do I have to use `IDispatch` interface's `Invoke()` method? If so, is there a way to find out what are the true method name strings to call? The wrapper uses numbers such as 0x109 above to address each method. Can I somehow harness the wrapper's `InvokeHelper()` to call methods directly on a given COM interface?

Comment: Proper COM interface pointer marshaling is unrelated to direct calling `IDispatch::Invoke`. Same standard rules apply. You just marshal the interface pointer the way you always do it.

Comment: Thanks Roman. You see, marshaling does not cause a problem. The problem is not being able to invoke any method on that interface, before or after it gets marshaled. The only way I know of to call methods on this ActiveX is through the wrapper class. The wrapper class extends `CWnd` object. The `InvokeHelper()` mechanism used by the Wrapper belongs to `CWnd.` But what good does the wrapper give me if I have a pointer to a raw interface? How can a call methods on this interface?

Comment: This code is auto-generated from the type library by the MFC wizard.  There is another way to do it, purely in code without using the wizard.  You'd use the [#import directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx).  Which does not use Dispatch::Invoke().  Before you get hot and heavy into it, do make sure that this component provides the proxy/stub you need.

Comment: I see now. As `InvokeHelper` is a relatively thin wrapper over `IDispatch::Invoke`, after marshaling `IDispatch` pointer to another thread, you can call the newly obtained `IDispatch::Invoke` method directly. Apparently you are interested in using the wrapping because in simplifies the call syntax, and one of the workarounds is to place the pointer into `CComPtr<IDispatch>` and use its `CComPtr<IDispatch>::Invoke0`, `Invoke1`, `InvokeN`, `PutProperty` helpers which are pretty close to original `InvokeHelper` in the functionality.

Comment: Roman. The Invoke0..1..2.. are different prototypes of `IDispatch::Invoke()`, I suppose? `CComPtr`, only helps in reference counting, not the actual function calls? I will try.. wanted to avoid since `IDispatch::Invoke()` do look unfriendly.

Comment: Hans, thanks.Your `#import` method sounds interesting, but without additional tips/references to code etc I am afraid I will spend days to find out how to make it work.

Comment: It's been a while since I used MFC, so my recollection is vague. The wrapper, I believe, is derived from `COleDispatchDriver`, which has a constructor from `IDispatch*` as well as `AttachDispatch` method. Using these, you might be able to obtain the raw `IDispatch` pointer, marshal it to another thread, and there create a new wrapper instance and attach the pointer to it. (continued).

Comment: That said, I question the point of the exercise. Most likely, the object is single-threaded. When you marshal it to another thread, you get a proxy. Any call on that proxy is marshaled back to the original thread, executed there, and the result marshaled back to the caller. That is, the worker thread doesn't actually do any work - all it does is sit there waiting for the original thread to return from the call. I doubt you would derive much benefit from marshaling to a worker thread in the first place.

Comment: Igor, good point and I agree. I am working with legacy code that just started to use ActiveX component (which previously was just plain old .dll) Marshaling a COM interface seems a smaller task than refactoring application to make the original thread the only client of the COM object.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. Igor your comment essentially answers my question, feel free to i give it as an answer and I accept it. My karma is too low to upvote your comment.

Comment: I think the same way as @IgorTandetnik, though I don't understand the exact situation. The fact that you're invoking the "real" underlying methods of your 3rd party ActiveX control should be the **same** whether you use the wapper functions or call the underlying methods, no? Also, in your answer, what's the point and what's the difference between using your code and using the above wrapper function in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quoting a response by Igor Tandetnik:

"It's been a while since I used MFC, so my recollection is vague. The wrapper, I believe, is derived from `COleDispatchDriver`, which has a constructor from `IDispatch` as well as `AttachDispatch` method. Using these, you might be able to obtain the raw `IDispatch` pointer, marshal it to another thread, and there create a new wrapper instance and attach the pointer to it."

Basically if you want to be using your MFC wrapper for COM/ActiveX objects after marshaling to another thread, you can use `COleDispatchDriver` to wrap your IDispatch and use some macro magic to tweek the code to invoke the same `InvokeHelper(..)` calls on the driver object. Alternatively extend the wrapper to use include acting on marshaled interface through the driver like the code below. Thanks, Igor.

```
void SetCommsWrite(short nAddress, float fValue)
{
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I2 VTS_R4 ;
    InvokeHelper(0x136, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, nAddress, fValue);
}
void SetCommsWrite(short nAddress, float fValue, COleDispatchDriver & driver)
{
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I2 VTS_R4;
    driver.InvokeHelper(0x136, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, nAddress, fValue);
}
```